# Error fitting a proportional hazards regression model to case-cohort data with cch function

Tags: r, cox-regression, cox

I am trying to fit a proportional hazards regression model to case-cohort data (where cases are oversampled and not representative of the population). I am using the `Survival` package and `cch()` function.

```
fit <- cch(Surv(followuptime, event) ~ A1 + A2 + A3, data =datadf, stratum=NULL, subcoh = datadf$subcoh, id=datadf$id, cohort.size=4512, method="Prentice")
```

The `A1`, `A2`, `A3` are metabolites, and I have 812 of them. When I fit the model with ~40 of them it works. But when I fit with more, I keep running into one of the following errors. I have no idea how to fix it and I would appreciate any help!

```
Error in if (any(exp(temp) > .Machine$double.xmax) || all(exp(temp) ==  :  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Error in agreg.fit(X, Y, istrat, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  : exp overflow due to covariates
```

Comment: looks like you have NAs in your data

Comment: no NAs at all in all my dataset !

Comment: can you share a reproducible example so we can run your code and get the error you have?